# OpenGL not throwing error and not showing difference in memory allocation for large 3D textures

Tags: c++, opengl, memory, nvidia

I am allocating a large 3D texture and seeing differences in program output, I suspect these differences to be caused by the system not having enough memory for the texture, but I am not sure how to verify and dynamically correct the issue.

The texture is allocated as:

```
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, side, side, side, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
```

When `side` is 512 the program works, when it is 1024 it doesn't.

However glGetError returns GL_NO_ERROR for both values.

In addition to that

`glGetIntegerv(GL_GPU_MEMORY_INFO_CURRENT_AVAILABLE_VIDMEM_NVX,&x);`

returns 7729 MB available out of 8192 regardless of the value of size.

Moreover calling `glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, temp*)` tells me that the maximum texture side is supposed to be 32768 (although I know that is for 2D textures and it probably does not apply to 3D textures).

I want to have the system crash or otherwise report to me that I am trying to allocate too much memory, or at least have a way to check myself if this is the case, alas none of the methods that I have been suggested seem to work.

## Update:

I have played around with stuff and found things that I am not happy with. First, I am able to get an out of memory error if I allocate textures that are large enough.

So my program has the following behavior:

-Small textures work
-Medium textures do not work and do not report errors
-Large textures do not work and report errors

I can't accept this, I need there to be only textures that work or textures that do not work and warn me about it, I cannot have textures that don't work without ever raising flags or issues.

Second, the treshohold for working vs not working fluctuates over time on the same machine independently of program execution.

So I ran the program a good chunk of times found a working vs not working threshold, then closed it and read some documentation, launched it again, and the treshold changed (so the threshold is stable across multiple program instances for a small period but not stable on the same machine over a long period). This has happened multiple times already. The working point is the same for multiple program launches when those instances are close to each other in time, but not if they are far away in time.

Checking memory using the nvidia extension results in the exam same code, so I have no reliable way of detecting when I have messed up.

TL;DR

I just want to know that I have messed up, it can be after the fact, I just want to eventually be told that my texture is too big and OpenGL failed to create the texture, I can't believe that there is no way to check for this, there has to be a way to someow detect that a texture is not working other than inspecting visual output.

Comment: OpenGL should never crash. If it does, it's a driver's bug.

Comment: You cna make it segfault, but regardless that's not the point. I just want to be told when I am trying to do something the system can't handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The enumerator `GL_MAX_3D_TEXTURE_SIZE` defines how big 3D textures can be, and 4.6 implementations are required to support at least 2048 per dimension.

Of course, this says nothing about *memory* limitations.

OpenGL implementations are not required to fulfill the execution of any function immediately (unless the function specifically says it does). They can defer things like memory allocation until whenever they like. As such, the error `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY` can be thrown *at any time*, regardless of when the operation that actually runs out of memory was executed.

> I just want to be told when I am trying to do something the system can't handle.

This is why Vulkan exists; OpenGL is simply not equipped to answer those questions immediately.

Comment: Is it possible to combine Vulkan and OpenGL in the same application then? Like, pre-calculate the size an OpenGL texture would have and then use vulkan to verify whether such a texture can actually be created?

Comment: @Makogan: That's not how you do things in Vulkan. In Vulkan, you ask how much memory a texture would cost (or more likely, how much all the textures you plan to use cost), and then you try to allocate that. If you get it, great; move forward. If you can't, then you need a fallback solution. You don't ask if there's enough memory for a texture because GPUs are shared; someone else might allocate that memory between when you ask and when you try to allocate. So you use the memory allocation functions as your way of asking if there's enough memory in an atomic way.

Comment: But is there a way to be informed, eventually, that the texture is too large? You say OGL cannot answer immediately, but can it ever answer it? All I want is a way to detect that the texture is not working other than visual output, I want an error to be raised, whenever but always.

Comment: @Makogan: As I said, it will give you an out-of-memory error. *Eventually*. But there will be no way to connect that error to the actual object that provoked it.

Comment: The issue however is that it does not throw an error. Like, I can leave the application running for minutes and still the notification message of glDebugMessage never gets called, it does for the largest of textures, but not for the medium sized textures, and that is what is bothering me.

Comment: @Makogan: What happens if you actually try to use the texture?

Comment: The output is black. When it works the output is a non-black color, when it does not work it remains black, but there is no error thrown.

Comment: @Makogan: BTW, there is no requirement that debug output will forward *all* OpenGL errors to you. Because OOM is such an oddball error, I wouldn't be surprised if it isn't hooked into that implementation's debug output system.

Comment: The issue is, I have tested it across multiple machines and it's the same behaviour